# INPUT[type=number] loses digits above Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER

Tags: html, validation, floating-point, long-integer

In my app, I have a value that is a 64-bit integer, output as the following HTML element:

```html
<input id="it" required="" type="number" name="SomeId" value="9123372036854775807">
```

In Firefox, when the element is loaded, it shows the value "9123372036854776000", and the adjustment arrows stop functioning.

This appears to be by design, as per the [relevant section of the HTML spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#number-state-(type%3Dnumber)):

> **The [algorithm to convert a string to a number](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#concept-input-value-string-number), given a string *input*, is as follows:** If applying the [rules for parsing floating-point number values](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/common-microsyntaxes.html#rules-for-parsing-floating-point-number-values) to *input* results in an error, then return an error; otherwise, return the resulting number.

That is, the input value is being parsed into a `Number`, which can't represent most long integers over 2 <sup>53</sup>.

How should I represent this long integer field as an HTML `input`, while still having good client-side validation?

Comment: I see that BigInt not work on Firefox (if you not turn it on in configuration...) so I think you need to use `input type="text"`

Comment: @KamilKiełczewski: is `type=bigint` supported in HTML, or is it only an ES feature?

Comment: I think that something like typ=bigint not exists in HTML

Answer (score 0):

Today, with ES2020 this is possible and not a pain.

```
<script setup lang="ts">
 const input = ref(1n) 
</script>

<template>
<input type="number" :value="input" 
@change="(v)=> { input= BigInt(v.currentTarget.value)}"/>
</template>
```

In this code snippet I'm using Vue3, but the logic is simple, the input is still a type="number" and the input value must be it the ES2020 format, with a "n" by the end.

If you need the bigInt as Hexadecimal, you can simply use .toString(16)

```
watch(() => input.value, () => {
  console.log('input.value', input.value);
  console.log('hex', (input.value).toString(16) ) ;
})
```

[Console logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RxZna.png)

And a good thing is that the input dont show the 'n' by the and, so the user will understand and the dev dont have to change the input

[Input img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cMznr.png)