# HTML-element "input" with type="number" and step="1e-15" doesn`t change value by press row buttons in some cases

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I create three instances of HTMLInputElement:
the first with `step="1e-15"` and `value="0"`;
the second with `step="1e-15"` and `value="5"`;
the third with `step="1e-14"` and `value="5"`.
After that I press "step up" button on each from these input fields.

```js
(function () {
let bufferInput = null;

bufferInput = document.querySelector( "#first" );
bufferInput.stepUp();

bufferInput = document.querySelector( "#second" );
bufferInput.stepUp();

bufferInput = document.querySelector( "#third" );
bufferInput.stepUp();
})()
```

```html
<label>step="1e-15" and initial value="0"</label>
<input id="first" type="number" value="0" min="-100" max="100" step="1e-15"><br>
<label>step="1e-15" and initial value="5"</label>
<input id="second" type="number" value="5" min="-100" max="100" step="1e-15"><br>
<label>step="1e-14" and initial value="5"</label>
<input id="third" type="number" value="5" min="-100" max="100" step="1e-14">
```

If I press "step up" manually, we get the same result.
As we can see from snippet above, input field values are incremented only for first and third from these input elements. Is there some maximum number of digits for an input field with `type="number"` or something else?

Comment: While it's mildly interesting that it does that with the `input` when the [near-equivalent](https://jsfiddle.net/nr5x4jg9/) just using code doesn't, you're playing *right at the edge* of the precision [the `number` type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number#number_encoding) can handle (*roughly* 15-17 digits of precision, depending on..things). If you really need to work with numbers at that scale reliably, you'll want to use something other than `number` (for instance: `bigint` using a fixed multiplier and then adding the `.` when rendering).

Comment: One wrinkle with that first "working" example is that once you reach a whole number, the step up stops working. If you enter 10000000000000000e-15 (i.e., 1) and click the up arrow, it reformats as 1 and remains there. Clicking the down arrow shows 0.999999999999999, but numbers above 1 don't work. Basically once your `step` gets below 1e-14, the `input type="number"` is no longer functional for numbers > 1 - step.

Comment: Does number type have so small precission, like 1e-14? I see that this is linked with number of digits, may be, becouse if I use as initial value for third input ```value="50"``` this sample doesn`t work too.

Comment: "for instance: bigint using a fixed multiplier and then adding the . when rendering". Is this something like in answer to question [`INPUT[type=number]` loses digits above `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54637550/inputtype-number-loses-digits-above-number-max-safe-integer)? In general, is input field helpfull for numbers with many digits in ineteger part or/and fraction part?